# How to put buttons next to eachother in kivy

Tags: python, button, formatting, kivy, kivy-language

I want to put my buttons 4 buttons next to eachother like this.https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGIFP.png
But I have my buttons like thishttps://i.stack.imgur.com/yts0z.png
How to change it .Here is my code. Hello now I added some more code, What if u want to combine it with other boxes.
Now I have 2 combine boxes. I have to questions and they will get 4 options each

```
ScrollView:
      GridLayout:
         rows: 3
         id :topic_grid
         size_hint_y: None
         spacing: 40,70
         height: self.minimum_height
         row_default_height: "3500dp"
         row_force_default: True
         BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            # question 1
            Label:
               color: 1,0,0,1
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Which team won the most titles in the SuperLig"
               font_size: 30
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Galatasary"
               size: 30,30
               border: (2, 2, 2, 2)

            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Fenerbahce"
               size: 30,30

            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Trabzonspor"
               size: 30,30

            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Besiktas"
               size: 30,30
            Label:
               color: 1,0,0,1
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Which team won the 1994 football world cup"
               font_size: 30
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Republic of Ireland"
               size: 30,30
               on_release:
                  self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Brazil"
               size: 30,30
               on_release:
                  self.background_color = 250,255,0,0.3
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "Germany"
               size: 30,30
               on_release:
                  self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
            Button:
               pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
               size_hint:1,1
               text: "USA"
               size: 30,30
               on_release:
                  self.background_color = 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use many `BoxLayout`s.
Every one of them can have any number of children (`Button`s or other `BoxLayout`s).

```py
ScrollView:
      GridLayout:
         rows: 3
         id :topic_grid
         size_hint_y: None
         spacing: 40,70
         height: self.minimum_height
         row_default_height: "3500dp"
         row_force_default: True
         BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            # question 1
            # Label:
            #    color: 1,0,0,1
            #    pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
            #    size_hint:1,1
            #    text: "Which team won the most titles in the SuperLig"
            #    font_size: 30
             BoxLayout:
                Button:
                   pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
                   size_hint:1,1
                   text: "Galatasary"
                   size: 30,30
                   border: (2, 2, 2, 2)

                Button:
                   pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
                   size_hint:1,1
                   text: "Fenerbahce"
                   size: 30,30

             BoxLayout:
                Button:
                   pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
                   size_hint:1,1
                   text: "Trabzonspor"
                   size: 30,30

                Button:
                   pos_hint:{"top": 1,"left": 1}
                   size_hint:1,1
                   text: "Besiktas"
                   size: 30,30
```

Comment: Hello but what if I want to combine it with other boxes.

Comment: i added some code , could u please check and help me, I want  to combine it with more boxes

Comment: Put every section in its own `BoxLayout`. Other than that, you have to be more specific...